# Loading packages into Julia does not work

Tags: macos

I installed Julia 1.0 on my iMac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I installed Julia and when I double click on it in my Applications folder, I get the expected screen shown below.

[image: Julia Screen]

But now that it's loaded it doesn't respond to commands as expected. In the instructions to set up Julia, I was instructed to load IJulia using the command `Pkg.add("IJulia")`. When I type this command I get the following message:

`ERROR: UndefVarError: Pkg not defined`

```
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

I've tried other commands to add packages and I get same error messages. Does anyone know why I can not load packages into Julia?

Comment: More appropriate for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: not really a programming question but i can try there.

Comment: `In the instructions to set up Julia, I was instructed to load IJulia using the command Pkg.add("IJulia").` Can you add a link/reference to this?

Comment: Here you go!  http://www.juliaopt.org/install.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pkg.add not working #627](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/627#issuecomment-412349679)

> You need `import Pkg` first. Or use the repl mode with `]` and then `add IJulia`.

Running `import Pkg` should resolve the issue.

Comment: Well I think that worked!  I got other error messages but I think everything loaded!  Wow - thanks for the help and quick reply!